# Transposition (Permutations)

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, definition, symmetric-groups

I have a definition in my notes that states a transposition is a permutation which interchanges two symbols and leaves all the others fixed. Thus, if $T$ is a transposition, then $\operatorname{sgn}(T)= -1$.

I understood transposition to be disjoint cycles of length 2. What does it mean when it says interchanges two symbols?

Comment: The wording of your last paragraph could be improved, but since it tells what you "understood" I'm hesitant to edit it for you. *A transposition* (singular) corresponds to a "cycle of length 2" (singular).  To speak of *disjoint* cycles requires having more than one cycle (the point being that two cycles are disjoint when there is no common symbol shared by them).

Comment: Thank you for this!

Answer (score 4):

It means that all but two symbols are fixed under the action of the transposition. "Symbols" here means elements of the set being acted on (conventionally $\{1,2,\ldots, n\}$ for elements of $S_n$).

For example, $(12)\in S_4$ would be a transposition, because it only interchanges the symbols $1$ and $2$, while leaving the symbols $3$ and $4$ fixed. On the other hand, $(12)(34)\in S_4$ would not be a transposition, because it interchanges $1$ and $2$ but also interchanges $3$ and $4$.

Comment: Thank you so much, makes so much sense. Sorry for my ignorance but what does sign(T)=-1 mean?

Comment: See here: [Parity of a permutation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation). $\operatorname{sgn}$ is a function that sends even parity permutations to $1$ and odd parity permutations to $-1$.

Comment: Also, if you had a larger set, i.e: n=10. Could (12)(34) exist in {1,2...10} ?As this would interchange 1 and 2, and 3 and 4, but the rest of the elements would be fixed?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Great! Thank you! (Learning the whole of my linear algebra module in 2 days.)

Comment: No problem, good luck.